# Xamarin Shiny: Running job repeatedly

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Using [shiny framework](https://github.com/shinyorg/shiny) by allan ritchie,
I have declared the repeated task as follows:

```
public class RepeatedTask : IJob
{
    public async Task<bool> Run(JobInfo jobInfo, CancellationToken cancelToken)
    {
        //do stuff

        return true;
    }
}
```

and the startup file is as follows

```
public class MyStartup : ShinyStartup
{
    public static JobInfo RepeatedJob;
    public override void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // register your shiny services here
        var job = new JobInfo(typeof(RepeatedTask))
        {
            Repeat = true,
            PeriodicTime = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().TimeOfDay,
            RequiredInternetAccess = InternetAccess.Any
        };
        RepeatedJob = job;
        services.RegisterJob(job);
    }
}
```

the task runs only once,
I want to run the task repeatedly for infinite time, how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

On `PeriodicTime` you should set a TimeSpan according with the interval you want the task run.

The minimum interval is 15 minutes, apparently, by a "limitation" of android nuget our higher